# WAMP: how to Re-Assign my old MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have the following problem with WAMP:

Due to my bad mistake I accidentally deleted 2 files from `www` directory, which had originally been there: 
`index.php` and `testmysql.php`.
All other folders are intact; But now when I open the link to PHPMyAdmin, it shows it completely fresh and empty; But my old mysql files are still in their folder.

How to assign back my MySQL databases into My Admin?

Comment: Seems like you killed more than 2 files ... and if you would have used an IDE your "history" might help you with the *.php files.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to specify the connection details to PHPMyAdmin again.  Remember, PHPMyAdmin is only a _client_ which talks to a MySQL server (locally). It does not hold any data itself.

Comment: How and where I can specify those connection details? P.S.djot -> No, it did happen because of IDE; and it took exactly 2 files: Usually I install everything in respective folders, but IDE installed Symfony in root, and because it was wrong, I deleted all files outside folders

Comment: it sounds like you've somehow deleted the link to phpmyadmin... you should still be able to call it directly by going to 
`http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

Comment: yes, i can open localhost/phpmyadmin , when I replaced those 2 files; but it is empty now.But MySQL data are in folder bin/mysql/etc

Comment: PHPMyadmin is just a php application that connects to mysql and gives you an interface to do things.  It does not contain mysql data, or is important to the functioning of mysql in any way.  packages like wamp just install the AMP stack and a set of applications that are preconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

if you need you old database then just make copy of your database files form 
here >> C:\wamp\bin\mysql\ and when you resinstal wamp replace this files and folder with new one. you will getback your old database.

Comment: Somehow it worked in re-installed wamp, when I copied the old MySQL folder; But I wonder it didn't work in the old; Thanks; may be it's because the new install have newer db version? - but now at least I can export data from new install and import back in in the old install..

Comment: Yes you are true sir if possible he can get all export from Command line or phpMyadmin or sqlYog that he can get backup of all mysql and utilized.